# How to suspend http requests until received and recorded token in localstorage?

Tags: angular, oauth, jwt, interceptor

I do authorization in an angular application. I get the CODE through the OAuth and send it to the backend. Backend returns me a token. But while I wait for the receipt and recording of the token, several BASE (for example a menu counter) requests return 401 errors. How can I save all requests and send them after writing a token to memory?

**Angular 7.2.0**

```js
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const currentToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    if (currentToken) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentToken}`
        }
      })
    }
    return next.handle((request));
  }
```

I would like to request data only after receiving the token, now I have to refresh the page to re-request all the data

Answer (score 0):

All the http requests are async in nature .So you have to make the calls for Menu inside the subscribe method of the backend call for Token. All subsequent calls also can be made inside it.

Answer (score 0):

From your service where you get the token you can make a subject which emits when you have set the token.

```
export class AccessTokenService {
  private readonly accessToken = new Subject<string>();
  readonly accessToken$ = accessToken.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    // your logic to get token:
    this.getTokenFromSomewhere().subscribe(() => {
      const token = localStorage.setItem('accessToken');
      this.accessToken.next(token);
    });
  }
}

export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(readonly at: AccessTokenService) {}

  public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.at.accessToken$.pipe(
      mergeMap((token) => {
        const request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        });

        return next.handle(request);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

You can also use the `APP_INITIALIZER` to set the localStorage item before anything else is loaded. But it depends on your use case if that's useful now